# Create python wrapper Using SWIG for C++ classes

Tags: python, swig

I have c++ object files

For example : 
example1.o and example2.o

1. Is it possible to create a python wrapper class using SWIG?
2. If yes how can I create using SWIG

Comment: http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus

Comment: @svs_swig Do you have the C++ source file ?

Comment: http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create wrapper without having the C++ source file but you need the header file because the interface file which you will define for Python wrapper generation, needs the C++ header files.

Using interface file wrapper can be generated by the following sample commands:

```
swig -c++ -python example.i
g++ -fpic -c example_wrap.cxx -I /usr/include/python2.7/
g++ --shared example.o example_wrap.o  -o _example.so
```

The example.o is the object file which you already have. You can then start a Python interpreter and type `import example` to verify that it is working.

Comment: @tcaswell Then where will be your definition of the method defined in the header file ? In the above example, example.c contains the functions defined in the header file.

Comment: @Sibi Thanks for your valuable time. I am going to try this.